# Javascript get weekday name from input

Tags: javascript, html

New here with JS.

How can i get all weekday names from a users input ? I'm trying to make 3 input boxes where you can fill in YYYY/MM/DD and then it should process it and with the specific date that the users given in the boxes it should tell if its a Sunday or Monday that specific date.

I have tried with this.

```
"use strict";
let f1 = document.createElement("p");
document.body.appendChild(f1);
f1.innerHTML = "Year?";
let r1 = document.createElement("input");
document.body.appendChild(r1);
r1.focus();

let f3 = document.createElement("p");
document.body.appendChild(f3);
f3.innerHTML = "Month?";
let r3 = document.createElement("input");
document.body.appendChild(r3);
r3.focus();


let f2 = document.createElement("p");
f2.innerHTML = "Day?";
document.body.appendChild(f2);
let r2 = document.createElement("input");
document.body.appendChild(r2);
r2.onchange = clicked;
let r = document.createElement("pre");
document.body.appendChild(r);



function Clicked(){
var now = new Date(r1.value,r3.value,r2.value);
```

And after that i have tried with GetDay but without luck so I'm stuck here.

Any kind of help would be nice.

Comment: now.getDay() should work.  How are you using it?

Comment: added an edit to your page to show how to call `getDay`. I believe it should function correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example of your code:

```js
"use strict";

const days = [
'Sunday',
'Monday',
'Tuesday',
'Wednesday',
'Thursday',
'Friday',
'Saturday',
];

let f1 = document.createElement("p");
document.body.appendChild(f1);
f1.innerHTML = "Year?";
let r1 = document.createElement("input");
document.body.appendChild(r1);
r1.focus();

let f3 = document.createElement("p");
document.body.appendChild(f3);
f3.innerHTML = "Month?";
let r3 = document.createElement("input");
document.body.appendChild(r3);
r3.focus();


let f2 = document.createElement("p");
f2.innerHTML = "Day?";
document.body.appendChild(f2);
let r2 = document.createElement("input");
document.body.appendChild(r2);

r2.onchange = Clicked;

let r = document.createElement("pre");
document.body.appendChild(r);

function Clicked() {
  var now = new Date(r1.value,r3.value-1,r2.value);
  r.innerHTML = days[now.getDay()];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice, that when you call `new Date` with year, month, day arguments, month needs to be one less. So January would not be 1, but 0.

Then you can use getDay() on the date.

```js
let now = new Date(2018, 10, 2); // 2nd of November (not October) 2018
console.log(now.getDay());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `date.toLocaleString(locale, { weekday: "long" })` to get day name

```js
"use strict";

const dayName = (date, locale = "en-US") =>
  date.toLocaleString(locale, { weekday: "long" });

let f1 = document.createElement("p");
document.body.appendChild(f1);
f1.innerHTML = "Year?";
let r1 = document.createElement("input");
document.body.appendChild(r1);
r1.focus();

let f3 = document.createElement("p");
document.body.appendChild(f3);
f3.innerHTML = "Month?";
let r3 = document.createElement("input");
document.body.appendChild(r3);
r3.focus();


let f2 = document.createElement("p");
f2.innerHTML = "Day?";
document.body.appendChild(f2);
let r2 = document.createElement("input");
document.body.appendChild(r2);
r2.onchange = Clicked;

let r = document.createElement("pre");
document.body.appendChild(r);

function Clicked() {
  var now = new Date(r1.value,r3.value-1,r2.value);
  r.innerHTML = dayName(now);
}
```